# JSON parseString similar to parseInt per javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I have some json:

```
     {
        "val":56,
        "desc":"data1"
     }
     ... //more list items.
```

that is being parsed from javascript.  I usually parse ints but never string.  Is there a parseString to get the desc string literal label below?

```
data.push([
    parseString(obj[i].desc), // <- not defined...is there an equivalent?
    parseInt(obj[i].val, 10)  // <- this is fine
]);
```

Essentially I'm trying to build the following to pass to highcharts pie chart:

```
data: [
    ['data1', 56],
    ['data2', 57],
    ['data3', 58]
]
```

Comment: Well after seeing how you're using `parseInt`, you most surely have a plain JS **object** and not a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj[i].desc` is already a string.  No additional parsing is necessary.  Remove `parseString()` and you're done.

Comment: And most likely don't need `parseInt` either then, the value is already an integer.